# Drag/Drop between medium/high integrity level processes in Windows Vista

Tags: security, windows-vista, process

In Windows Vista, I am unable to drag/drop files onto my application's window because it is running as a high integrity level process. I need to run it as high, but I also need to be able to accept dropped files from low/medium integrity level processes like Windows Explorer. I believe it is UIPI that is blocking the drag/drop operation. I know that I can use the ChangeWindowMessageFilter function to allow certain Windows messages to bypass UIPI, but I'm not sure which messages to add to allow the drag/drop operation. Is ChangeWindowMessageFilter the right approach to permit this, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the title of this blog entry:
"[**Why you shouldn’t touch `Change­Window­Message­Filter` with a 10-ft pole…**](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=151)",
I guess it is not the best approach ;)

> Now, this might seem like a great approach at first - after all, you’ll only use `Change­Window­Message­Filter` when you’re sure you can completely validate a received message even if it is from an untrusted source, such that there’s no way something could go wrong, right?
>
> Well, the problem is that even if you do this, **you are often opening your program up to attack unintentionally**.
>   Consider for a moment how custom window messages are typically used; virtually all the common controls in existence have “dangerous” messages in the custom class message range (e.g. WM_USER and friends).
>
> Additionally, many programs and third party libraries confuse `WM_USER` and `WM_APP`, such that you may have programs communicating cross process via both `WM_USER` and `WM_APP`, via “dangerous” messages that are used to make sensitive decisions or include pointer parameters.

---

In the comments of this blog entry, an alternative approach was discussed, but with pretty much the same conclusion:

> I would use `RegisterWindowMessage` and then allow that via `ChangeWindowMessageFilter`.
>   However, be aware that you cannot design a cross-process window message interface that passes pointers or other untrusted values or you are creating a security hole.
>
> For this reason, I would tend to avoid using window at all messages for most cross-process IPC (if possible), as it is typically very difficult to do non-trivial things in a secure fashion using them.

---

Note: this entry "[So, who wants to design a feature today?](http://rageshkrishna.com/blog/2008/01/02/SoWhoWantsToDesignAFeatureToday.aspx)" illustrates the same problem, and points to the insightful articles of Raymond Chen:

- [Why aren't console windows themed on Windows XP?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/31/6909007.aspx)
- [Windows Vista has more extended options on the context menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/22/4500831.aspx#4511968)

which both detail the issue.
This ServerFault question "[Why can’t I drag/drop a file for editing in notepad in Windows Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39600/why-cant-i-drag-drop-a-file-for-editing-in-notepad-in-windows-server-2008)" also includes some answers, but no quick-win.

See also this [article on IE](http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/fix-third-party-input-language-method-editor-ime-issues-in-ie-and-windows-vista-by-disabling-uipi/)

Comment: I'm aware of the dangers of opening my application up using this method, and as such I'm not passing any pointer structures around. I really need the drag/drop functionality to work, and Vista's "security" is really starting to annoy me.

Comment: I understand: note you may find some other suggestions at this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/39600/why-cant-i-drag-drop-a-file-for-editing-in-notepad-in-windows-server-2008 (including disabling the UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation))

Comment: Unfortunately I can't ask the users of my application to disable UIPI. I understand the reasoning behind blocking the drag/drop operation between priority levels, but it really makes app development unnecessarily complicated. :(